# Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, laravel, connection

```
public function unprepared($query)
{
    return $this->run($query, [], function ($query) {
        if ($this->pretending()) {
            return true;
        }
    
        $this->recordsHaveBeenModified(
            //** This Line: **
            $change = $this->getPdo()->exec($query) !== false
        );
        return $change;
    });
}
```

```
location error : {"exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1):
 Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:512)
```

Comment: Please can you show the query you're trying to run when you get this error.

Comment: what is  query possible clarification?

Comment: It looks like you'll be running some sort of database query e.g. `DB` or a model, so what is the code you're trying to run when you get this error?

Comment: I run email verification and get this error

Comment: Please can you show the code you're running.